# What does the character in this Naruto poster mean?

Tags: meaning, character-identification, characters

I dont know how to type that character, otherwise I would try it out through other means.

What does the character mean? It appears in a poster concerning the Japanese manga Naruto.

[image: naruto poster: bonds]

Comment: Looks like a poster for the Japanese anime movie, _Naruto Shippuden The Movie: Bonds_ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That looks like 絆 (traditional character). The simplified one is 绊. Chinese pronunciation is bàn and it can mean:

1. to trip
2. to get in the way
3. to hold ... up
4. it can also refer to 绊子 which is a wrestling technique that is executed by throwing the opponent over one's leg; to hurt somebody without letting them know

In Japanese it stands for kizuna and means bonding, connections between people or bonds (just as the picture says).

Answer (score 3):

This is not Chinese, it's Japanese(絆). The meaning of the character in very different in the two languages now.

The meaning of the symbol is already shown in the picture : bonds (between friends, family members, etc.)